# SSRS 2012 Report with Oracle database as datasource never finishes

Tags: sql-server, oracle, ssrs-2012

I am investigating a SSRS 2012 Report which used to return data from an Oracle database. However, recently it stopped returning data. The report will sit there and run forever until something times out. Our report catalog database is also on a separate server which does not show any issues in the logs or while monitoring the performance. I do not see any errors in the Event log, SQL Server Logs, Reporting Services logs or the Oracle database logs. If I strip out the query from the report it returns rows in a few minutes. Is there a method for monitoring what is happening with the communication between the report server and the oracle server? How can I troubleshoot this issue if none of the logs are reporting any problems?

Looks like I am now getting Timeout errors in the report logs.

```
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Timeout expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding.
```

When I run the query against the Oracle database using SQL Plus, it takes about 8 minutes to run.

Comment: I wonder if it is timing out just trying to get to the Oracle database. You should check your connection and query. It might help to build a new SSRS report that does something much faster and see if that works. Could the Oracle IP address or port have changed?

Comment: Definitely getting some timeout issues now. I will update the question with more information.

Comment: My point was is this a case where tuning on the Oracle side will resolve it, or are you just not getting connected to Oracle.

Comment: were you able to solve this ? I have similar issue.

Comment: @ved got pulled onto other projects but I may be revisiting this one soon.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend the following:

1) Run the report and check Oracle's session (v$session) view to see if the Oracle database even registered the connection and the query was passed to it.

a) if YES, then check your report server's timeout settings. If the initial data return is elapsing the timeout period in either your report or your RS config file, this may likely be the reason for your timeout issue. You can check out report timeout periods in your data source configurations. You can check time out RS settings in your report server's config file.

b) if NO, you've got something else going that is more fundamental in connecting to the Oracle db and submitting the query.

Answer (score 0):

I guess maybe timeout error is not for connection and receive data, maybe it is because your report design is very complicated. I suggest create new report with the same dataset and without any design (blank report) and check if the timeout error exists. In the next step you can add a table to show a short field (like id) and so on.